# Jmeter - How to add "counter" inside other variable in http request parameters

Tags: jmeter

I'm getting variables from Cassandra(DataBase) request so my vars from Cassandra can be from `id_0` to `id_19`.
I'm running in while controller so for each one I need to increment the id number.
I used counter with this code: `${story_id_${counter}}` , 
but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JMeter user manual,](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#what_can_do)

> Note that variables cannot currently be nested; i.e ${Var${N}} does
>   not work. The __V (variable) function (versions after 2.2) can be used
>   to do this: ${__V(Var${N})}. In earlier JMeter versions one can use
>   ${__BeanShell(vars.get("Var${N}")}